# Increment Number in Image Source On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to create next and previous buttons for a JQuery Image Gallery I'm working on. Each button has an id of "next" and "prev" respectively. What I'm trying to do is change a number that is in the source of the main image in the gallery (which has an id of mainImg). I have been able to target the number within the source of each image but I can't seem to increment it correctly and then replace the current image's source number with the new, incremented number. I tried using a while loop, for loop, and if statement but none of them worked correctly. To see the gallery that I have so far, I have it uploaded here: http://tiger.towson.edu/~abarso2/463/projecta/index.html If you go into my script.js file you'll see a block commented out at the bottom. That is the function I have so far that targets the number within the image's source and parses it to an integer. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's what I have currently:

```
(function(){
    var mainImg = $('#mainImg').attr('src');
    var mainImgStr = mainImg.charAt(mainImg.length - 5);
    var mainImgNum = parseInt(mainImgStr);
        $('#next').click(function(){

        });
}());
```

Comment: You'll want to copy/paste what you have so far in your question, if you want to increase your chances of getting a solid answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
$(function(){
    var mainImg = $('#mainImg');
    var slidshow = $('#slideShow');

    $('#next').click(function(){
        var src = mainImg.attr('src').replace('thumb','shot');
        var next = $('img[src="' + src +'"]', slidshow).next();
        if(next.length){
            mainImg.attr('src',next.attr('src').replace('thumb','shot'));
        }
    });

    $('#prev').click(function(){
        var src = mainImg.attr('src').replace('thumb','shot');
        var prev = $('img[src="' + src +'"]', slidshow).prev();
        if(prev.length){
            mainImg.attr('src',prev.attr('src').replace('thumb','shot'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked great until I put all of the images within the #slideShow div into list items in an unordered list. I tried modifying your code to get it to work correctly now but I can't seem to get it right. Would it be possible for you to revise this so that it draws from list items instead of just images?

Comment: If you go to the link I posted in my original question you can see exactly how I've formatted the #slideShow div now.

Comment: You need to change to `next.parent().children('img').attr('src')` and `prev.parent().children('img').attr('src')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the revised code. The regexp will work better. The user can click the next button multiple times but no image will be skipped as the main image will only go to the next if and when the next image is loaded. So if you click next quickly 5 times only the next image will show (not skipping 4 images).

```
(function(){
 // replace all non digit characters from src
 // only the last set of numbers so www.123.com/image7.jpg
 // will give us 7
 function getNumber(src){
   return parseInt(src.replace(/[\d]+(?=[\/])/g,"")
    .replace(/[^\d]/g,""),10);
 }
 // replaces last number of a source with the number provided
 // www.123.com/imgage7.jpg will be www.123.com/image8.jpg
 // if number 8 is given
 function setNumber(src,num){
   return src.replace(/[\d]+(?![\d])/g,num);
 }
 var $mainImg = $('#mainImg');
 $('#next').click(function(){
  var src= $mainImg.attr('src'),
  mainImgNum = getNumber(src);
  var $img=$(document.createElement("img"));
  $img.data("checkNext",false);
  $img.on("load",function(){
    // image exsist, load it as main image src
    if($img.data("checkNext")===true){
      $img.remove();
    }else{
      $mainImg.attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
      $("#prev").show(1000);
      $img.data("checkNext",true);
      $img.attr('src',setNumber($img.attr('src'),
       new String(mainImgNum+2));
  });
  $img.on("error",function(){
    if($img.data("checkNext")===true){
      $("#next").hide(1000);
    }
    // clean up
    $img.remove();
  });
  $img.attr('src',setNumber(src,new String(mainImgNum+1)));
 });
}());
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much that seems to have done the trick! Now I just need to know one more thing. If I've reached the last image I want it to stop there and vice versa for the previous button (which also works thanks to your code). I imagine that I will need to check to see if the mainImgNum is equal to the number of thumbnails that I have and if it is, I want to hide the next button. Would you know how I could do this?

Comment: Updated my answer, please not that the images have to be sequential or the script breaks.

Comment: Updated again, this one is using better regexp and won't break when clicking really fast while images load really slow.